# Typeorm migrations and dist folder in docker container

Tags: docker, migration, nestjs, typeorm

i have a project in nestjs and typeorm with docker. Every time I create a migration with the command "yarn typeorm migrations:create ..." it works fine. However, if I rename this migration, inside the dist folder of the docker container it will be "duplicated".
Example:

- yarn typeorm migrations:create -n CreateColumnOwner
- rename 1646331377238-CreateColumnOwner to 1646331377238-CreateColumnOwnerInTable
- In the dist folder of the container I will have two files: 1646331377238-CreateColumnOwner AND 1646331377238-CreateColumnOwnerInTable

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

docker-compose:

```
admin:
    container_name: admin
    build:
      context: services/admin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    volumes:
      - $PWD/services/admin:/usr/src/app
      - $PWD/services/admin/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - $HOME/.cache/yarn:/yarncache
    command: yarn start:dev
    networks:
      - company-net
    ports:
      - 3005:3005
```

Comment: Could you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Its done!!!!!!!

Comment: got any .dockerignore? it would be a good idea to add dist to your dockerignore when you do a COPY . . you might copy that wich will explain both files